# Delete everything in file after last appearance string

Tags: python, xml, string, reverse

I want to make a program which look through files, finds every incomplete file (without `</module>` at the end), then it will print last found abnumber in file and delete everyline (including the last with abnumber) after it.

So my file looks like that:

```
<Module bs="Mainfile_1">
<object id="1000" name="namex" abnumber="1">
    <item name="item0" value="100" />
    <item name="item00" value="100" />
</object>
<object id="1001" name="namey" abnumber="2">
    <item name="item1" value="100" />
    <item name="item00" value="100" />
</object>
<object id="1234" name="name1" abnumber="3">
    <item name="item1" value="something11:

something11" />
    <item name="item2" value="233" />
    <item name="item3" value="233" />
    <item name="item4" value="something12:

12something" />
</object>
<object id="1238" name="name2" abnumber="4">
    <item name="item8" value="something12:
    <item name="item9" value="233" />
```

and at the end it should looks like:

```
<Module bs="Mainfile_1">
<object id="1000" name="namex" abnumber="1">
    <item name="item0" value="100" />
    <item name="item00" value="100" />
</object>
<object id="1001" name="namey" abnumber="2">
    <item name="item1" value="100" />
    <item name="item00" value="100" />
</object>
<object id="1234" name="name1" abnumber="3">
    <item name="item1" value="something11:

something11" />
    <item name="item2" value="233" />
    <item name="item3" value="233" />
    <item name="item4" value="something12:

12something" />
</object>
```

with printed: 4

I started by doing something like that but I feel like I am doing everything wrong:

```
import os

Mainfile = 'path'
for filename in os.listdir(Mainfile):
    lines = filename.readlines()
    if not "</Module>" in lines:
        with open(filename, 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as file:
            line_list = list(file)
            line_list.reverse()
            for line in line_list:
                if line.find('absno') != -1:
                    print(line)
```

Comment: Do you know `</module>` is missing in advance? if yes, just append it at the end of the string and try to parse it as xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` to get your result :

`<object([\s\S]*?)<\/object>` to get correct `<object... </object>` tag

`abnumber=\"([0-9.]+)` to get abnnumber for incorrect tag

`<Module.*|<object(?:[\s\S]*?)<\/object>` to get correct format of xml data

```
import re

data = """<Module bs="Mainfile_1">
<object id="1000" name="namex" abnumber="1">
    <item name="item0" value="100" />
    <item name="item00" value="100" />
</object>
<object id="1001" name="namey" abnumber="2">
    <item name="item1" value="100" />
    <item name="item00" value="100" />
</object>
<object id="1234" name="name1" abnumber="3">
    <item name="item1" value="something11:

something11" />
    <item name="item2" value="233" />
    <item name="item3" value="233" />
    <item name="item4" value="something12:

12something" />
</object>
<object id="1238" name="name2" abnumber="4">
    <item name="item8" value="something12:
    <item name="item9" value="233" />"""


invalid_XML_Tag = re.sub("<object([\s\S]*?)<\/object>", '', data)
abnnumber_value = re.findall("abnumber=\"([0-9.]+)", invalid_XML_Tag)
print("abnumber of invalid tag => {0}".format(abnnumber_value))

correct_xml_format = re.findall("<Module.*|<object(?:[\s\S]*?)<\/object>",data)
print("".join(correct_xml_format))
```

**Output:**

```
 abnumber of invalid tag => ['4']
<Module bs="Mainfile_1"><object id="1000" name="namex" abnumber="1">
    <item name="item0" value="100" />
    <item name="item00" value="100" />
</object><object id="1001" name="namey" abnumber="2">
    <item name="item1" value="100" />
    <item name="item00" value="100" />
</object><object id="1234" name="name1" abnumber="3">
    <item name="item1" value="something11:

something11" />
    <item name="item2" value="233" />
    <item name="item3" value="233" />
    <item name="item4" value="something12:

12something" />
</object>
```